# They were used to ........ of being rich. (choices are "living, the life, live, a life")

Tags: word-choice

They were used to ........ of being rich. (choices are "living, the life, live, a life")

All I know is that "used to" is followed by the infinitive form of the verb, but it seems to be more natural. I think it may be "the life" but I am confusing both "the life" and "live", which one should I use?

Does "used to live of being rich" have a meaning?

If the two of them can be used, then what is the difference in meaning?

I tried to answer this question but I couldn't.

Comment: "Used to" meaning "accustomed to" does not always have to be followed by an infinitive verb or even a verb at all.

Comment: so what is the most natural answer grammatically ? @MichaelWokeHarvey

Comment: The two verbs (*live* and *living*) are definitely ungrammatical, but none of your choices are very natural. Two more natural ways of phrasing this in English would be: *They were used to being rich,* or *They were used to a life of luxury.*